# How to remove lines from the output of a command in a bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to do a command that gives multiple lines; eg `ldapwhoami` and Id like to make it in a bash script that prints only the last line instead of all the command lines.
I tried the following

```
#/bin/bash
$(ldapwhoami | sed 1d2d3d)
```

but it doesn't seem to work, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for `tail -n1`

Comment: `head` and `tail` will do such tasks https://ss64.com/bash/tail.html

Comment: *"that prints only the last line"* -- [`tail`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html) is the command you are looking form.

Comment: If *all* the content you want to be rid of is on stderr, maybe you should just be using `ldapwhoami 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: ...that said, ignoring your error logs (as opposed to filtering out specific content or telling the command not to generate it in the first place) is generally a bad idea. Some day your LDAP server will be down and the 3 lines of stderr will have different contents, but they'll still be blocked from view.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for your input! i will make sure to keep that in mind. btw, may i ask another quick question about LDAP here?

Comment: If by "here" you mean "on the site", sure -- so long as it's more about programming/development/scripting than about LDAP administration (which would tend to be a better fit for ServerFault).

Comment: Ah, it is indeed about LDAP but I cant post a new question and Im a bit stuck in a hurry. But i understand, thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print only the final line use `tail`:

```
ldapwhoami | tail -n 1
```

To delete the first three lines with `sed`, change your command to:

```
ldapwhoami | sed '1d;2d;3d;'
```

note the semicolons and the quotes

Also possible with `awk`

```
ldapwhoami | awk 'NR > 3'
```

The above assumes that all output goes to standard output. In unix though there are two output streams that are connected to each process, the standard output (denoted with 1 - that is used for the output of the program), and the standard error (denoted with 2 - that is used for any diagnostic/error messages). The reason for this separation is that it is often desirable not to "pollute" the output with diagnostic messages, if it is processed by another script.

So for commands that generate output on both steams, if we want to capture both, we redirect the standard error to standard output, using `2>&1`) like this:

```
ldapwhoami 2>&1 | tail -n 1
```

(for awk and sed the same syntax is used)

In bash, the above may be written using shorthand form as

```
ldapwhoami |& tail -n 1
```

If all you need is the standard output, and you don't care about standard error, you can redirect it to `/dev/null`

```
ldapwhoami 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: I tried the tail -n but it doesn't seem to be working, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @HiThere: Please add the exact command you are running

Comment: #/bin/bash
ldapwhoami | tail -n 1
is the bash script im trying to run. But it keeps giving me the first 4 lines of the command ldapwhoami even after I added the tail.

Comment: @HiThere: Maybe the command is printing to `stderr`, try `ldapwhoami 2>&1 | tail -n 1
`

Comment: That worked! Could you please explain to me stderr and why the command worked now?

Comment: @HiThere: Added an explanation, let me know if anything is still unclear

Comment: When deleting lines 1 through 3 with sed you may do `sed '1,3d'` for brevity.